# Repeat static row on new page of tablix, included in another tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a 1:n relation from company to visit reports. I want to display details of related visit report in a tablix.

So I created one tablix with grouping on company-id and put a second tablix (grouping on visit-report-id) in the second tablix cell.

Here is a figure:

```
topmost tablix                                 
----------------------------------------------
|            |          included tablix       |
|            | -------------------------------
|            | | Details1 | Details 2| ...    | <-- static row
| [company   | |------------------------------
|    name]   | | [val 1]  | [val 2]  | [val n]| <-- grouping on visit report id
|            | --------------------------------
|            |                                |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to repeat the marked static row on each new page. I tried a lot of different constellation regarding 'RepeatOnNewPage', 'KeepWithGroup', 'KeepTogether', 'Repeat row headers on each page' options.

I also tried to use only one tablix with 2 row groups, but there is the problem, that the company name will be repeated with every of its visit reports.

Is there a trick/workaround to achive to repeat the header row on each page or is it not possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, at this stage that you've already created the report, I would do this:

1- Create a second dataset getting the distinct Details for each Company (basically one level of granularity less than original dataset). 2- Insert one empty row above "Val" row. 3- Use Lookup function to bring in the Detail values from second dataset.

Comment: I dont understand how this solution could fix the problem of repeating the static row of the inner tablix on each new page.